# Managing maven versions when doing a deploy

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I come to you looking for best practices on maven + version management.

I am trying to deploy a proyect to an artifact repository, but I'd like the version to be referred to the scm-version. I need to do this because I have many developers working against different "revisions" of the deployed library.

The pom configuration is the following:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx.xxx-parent</artifactId>
<version>${version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<namexxxx Parent</name>
```

and when I do:

```
mvn deploy source:jar -Dversion=r203
```

the project is deployed correctly to the artifact repository..

The problem is, by adding the **${version}** I am forcing everyone to use the **-Dversion=** when running any maven command.

I also thought of defining a property on the profiles.xml file but I am not sure this is the best way to do it.

What would you recommend to do on this situation?

Thanks a lot,
Lucas

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using the [versions plugin](http://mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) for maven

Comment: For the OP. We had the same problem, multiple devs using about 60 or so trunks with different versions. Managed to fix it by writing a groovy script to call versions-maven-plugin mentioned by Mark after it checked out all repos (or those that were in a file). Not the best way but it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SVN, which it looks like, [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) might be an option.